# Defining object as a Constant in Ecma-Script-6

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have the following code for Ecma-Script-6 template constants.

```
const person = 'John Smith';
console.log(person);

person = 'Naeem Shaikh';    
console.log("{{After changing the value for person.name}}");

console.log(person);
```

of-course it doesn't work. http://www.es6fiddle.net/i3vhumdx/ It gives following error,

```
person is read-only
```

now the same thing i do with an object.

```
const person = {name: 'John Smith'};

console.log(JSON.stringify(person));

person.name='Naeem Shaikh';
person.age="24";

console.log("{{After changing the value for person.name}}");

console.log(JSON.stringify(person));
```

http://www.es6fiddle.net/i3vhzblm/

Output is:

```
{"name":"John Smith"}
{{After changing the value for person.name}}
{"name":"Naeem Shaikh","age":"30"}
```

here I am able to write into a read-only object without any problem. Can anyone explain this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have the same behavior when changing the argument passed to a function from inside that function : if it's a string, the external one isn't changed, if it's an object and you change a property, it is changed.

The point is what the value of a variable is :

- for an object, it's a reference to the object, you don't change that reference
- for a string, it's a reference to the string, which happens to be **immutable**

When you're changing the properties, you don't change the value (the reference to the object).

An extract of [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) :

```
// const also works on objects
const myObject = {"key": "value"};

// However, object attributes are not protected,
// so the following statement is executed without problems
myObject.key = "otherValue";
```

What you seem to want is to have a constant **immutable** object. [Freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) it :

```
const person = Object.freeze({name: 'John Smith'});
```

This way it wouldn't be possible to change the name of the person.

Comment: http://www.es6fiddle.net/i3vi7or9/  I  am not changing the reference here in this fiddle right? but it works like a constant

Comment: Your assigning a new value to the person variable : you try to make it refer to another object.

Comment: ok so `reference` and `freeze` is the key words here.. Bcoz of having a reference value object would behave a little different as a constant and To overcome it we should freeze it. do I get it now?

Comment: I think you get it. Be careful (in more complex cases) that freezing isn't recursive (it doesn't freeze properties of property values when they're not immutable).